# Workflow Foundation Compilation Error - Help!

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation

I am working on a WCF Workflow Service Application, and I simply have a Receive activity that is taking input from a client application, then passing the input to a remote web service,calculating a result, and returning the result to the client site.

I am attempting to setup the result for the remote web service, but it is giving me the following error:

**Compilation error(s) encountered while processing expression:Option Strict On disallows 
implicit conversion from Object to Double.**

I understand what this is saying, and I have tried a couple work arounds. For example, I have set the Object to string, and attempted to parse it to double, but got the same result.

Here is what I am looking at to give a better idea. You can see the variables on the bottom of the screen are what I am attempting to set the result to.

You can see where the red error circle is, is where my compilation error is.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using double as the type of Variable1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, variable1 needs to be a Double, or you need to put an explicit cast in the CalculateMonthlyPaymentResult assignment. I vote for the former as it is more correct. If you need to return a double, then that is the data type that the workflow should be working with rather than Object which the variable is current defined as.